# What should be used between Doc2Vec and Word2Vec when analyzing product reviews?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, doc2vec

I collected some product reviews of a website from different users, and I'm trying to find similarities between products through the use of the embeddings of the words used by the users.
I grouped each review per product, such that I can have different reviews succeeding one after the other in my dataframe (i.e: different authors for one product). Furthermore, I also already tokenized the reviews (and all other pre-processing methods). Below is a mock-up dataframe of what I'm having (the list of tokens per product is actually very high, as well as the number of products):

| Product | reviews_tokenized |
| --- | --- |
| XGame3000 | absolutely amazing simulator feel inaccessible ... |
| Poliamo | production value effect tend cover rather ... |
| Artemis | absolutely fantastic possibly good oil ... |
| Ratoiin | ability simulate emergency operator town ... |

However, I'm not sure of what would be the most efficient between doc2Vec and Word2Vec. I would initially go for Doc2Vec, since it has the ability to find similarities by taking into account the paragraph/sentence, and find the topic of it (which I'd like to have, since I'm trying to cluster products by topics), but I'm a bit worry about the fact that the reviews are from different authors, and thus might bias the embeddings? Note that I'm quite new to NLP and embeddings, so some notions may escape me. Below is my code for Doc2Vec, which giving me a quite good silhouette score (~0.7).

```
product_doc = [TaggedDocument(doc.split(' '), [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(df.tokens)]
model3 = Doc2Vec(min_count=1, seed = SEED, ns_exponent = 0.5)
model3.build_vocab(product_doc)
model3.train(product_doc, total_examples=model3.corpus_count, epochs=model3.epochs)
product2vec = [model3.infer_vector((df['tokens'][i].split(' '))) for i in range(0,len(df['tokens']))]
dtv = np.array(product2vec)
```

What do you think would be the most efficient method to tackle this? If something is not clear enough, or else, please tell me.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Below is the clusters I'm obtaining:
[image: Clusters obtained]

Comment: Why are you training your own embedding ? Have you tried using pre-trained doc2vec or word2vec model (or even [transformer](https://huggingface.co/) ?) ? If you have multiple reviews per product I suggest you encode each review by itself and then find a way of combining them (so the documents aren't too long and they are segmented). What is your goal with the clustering you are doing ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are going to do. But you can use word2vec to give each word a vector, and doc2vec to give each document a vector. Also, you can get average of word2vec vectors to get a vector for a document.

Comment: @ygorg The goal is to regroup products together, using the users' reviews as a way to find similarities between products (users might use some similar words to describe some products, thus those products could be clustered together). I indeed used a pre-trained model (wiki-news-300d-1M to be precise), but the silhouette score was lower than when training it on my own model (which is quite huge so I thought it wouldn't be an issue).

Comment: @parvanehshayegh I described the goal in my other comment, but the idea was that since doc2vec can take into account the paragraph/sentence, to remember what is missing from the current context/topic, I thought it would the most efficient.

Comment: I am not familiar with the silhouette score, is 0.7 a good score ? Were you able to evaluate the embeddings you trained ? Have you checked the clusters to see whether they "looked" nice. Do you know some items that should be in the same cluster, so you have some reference to evaluate ? Also you are dealing with use-generated text, so a model trained on social media might be better than one trained on wikipedia.

Comment: Just copy/pasting Wikipedia on this one, but "silhouette is a measure of how similar an object is to its own cluster (cohesion) compared to other clusters (separation). The silhouette ranges from −1 to +1, where a high value indicates that the object is well matched to its own cluster and poorly matched to neighboring clusters". The clusters look indeed nice (I edited my post to include them). The social media model is also a good idea, I'll try with that!

Comment: What I meant with my question was more : is the silhouette score relevant for your case. And by "looking at" I meant to study which items are part of a cluster and whether it made sense. From the graphic you show it seem like all the samples are pretty close to each other. No cluster really emerges from the picture. Also how do you choose the number of cluster according to your data ?

Comment: The silhouette is indeed relevant in my case. I chose the number of clusters according to a series of method (elbow and david-boulding), that suggested me that number (4). For the shape of the clusters, I really don't know if a shape like the one I obtained is correct or "good". Ah, forgot to add that I did a PCA, if it helps to explains its shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to tell which particular mix of methods will work best for a specific dataset and particular end-goal: you really have to try them against each other, in your own reusable pipeline for scoring them against your desired results.

It looks like you've already stripped the documents down to keywords rather than original natural text, which could hurt with these algorithms - you may want to try it both ways.

Depending on the size & format of your texts, you may also want to look at doing "Word Mover's Distance" (WMD) comparisons between sentences (or other small logical chunks of your data). Some work has demo'd interesting results in finding "similar concerns" (even with different wording) in the review domain, eg: https://tech.opentable.com/2015/08/11/navigating-themes-in-restaurant-reviews-with-word-movers-distance/

Note, though, WMD gets quite costly to calculate in bulk with larger texts.